# Error after implementing NicEdit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**The Idea:**

Recently I have implemented a wysiwyg editor called NicEdit which changed all my textareas to NicEdit wysiwyg editor (Basically, it is a forum. So implementing a wysiwyg editor would make things easy for the users). I programmed my textarea in such a way  that u get an alert box saying "please type something into the body" if u click submit without entering anything. If u enter something and post, u will be redirected to the page where u have posted.

**The Problem:**

Now I'm facing a problem after implementing NicEdit wysiwyg editor. When I enter something in the textarea and hit submit the following is happening

- Firstly, the alert box is being displayed which say "please type something into the body".
- And then immediately, i'm being redirected to the page where I have posted.

I don't want that alert box to pop up.

**Code:**

```
<script src="js/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script>bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
```

nicEdit.js is pretty long. I followed the installation guide for NicEdit and it asked me to include the above two lines of code only. But after I did that, I'm facing the above mentioned problem.

Anyone who implemented NicEdit faced the same problem?? If so, please suggest me a solution.

**Edit:**

this is the html content in my page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/forumstyle.css">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/editor.css">-->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<!--<script src="js/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script>bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
<!--<script src="js/editor.js"></script>--> 
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script> 
function validateMyForm ( ) 
{ 
    var isValid = true;
    if ( document.form1.post_title.value == "" ) 
    { 
        alert ( "Please type in a title for this topic" ); 
        isValid = false;
    } 
    else if ( document.form1.post_title.value.length < 10 ) 
    { 
        alert ( "Your title must be at least 10 characters long" ); 
        isValid = false;
    } 
    else if ( document.form1.post_body.value == "" ) 
    { 
        alert ( "Please type in your topic body." ); 
        isValid = false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
/*function submit_form(){
    var theForm = document.getElementById("form1");
    theForm.elements["post_body"].value = document.getElementsByClassName("nicEdit-selected").innerHTML;
    theForm.submit();
}*/
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
<div id="pageMiddle">
  <div id="leftPanel">
    <a href="viewFriends.php"><img src="images/friendsImage.png" ></a>
    <a href="photos.php"><img src="images/galleryImage.png" ></a>
    <a href="messages.php"><img src="images/messagesImage.png"></a>
    <a href="forumhome.php"><img src="images/forumImage.png"></a>
  </div>
  <div id="middlePanel">
    <table style="background-color:#FFF; border:#069 1px solid; border-top:none;" width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="80%" valign="top">
          <h2><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></h2>
          <div id="breadcrumbs"><a href="forumhome.php">Forum</a>&larr;<a href="sections.php?id=<?php echo $forum_section_id; ?>"><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></a></div><br /><br />
          <h2>Creating New Topic In the  <em><?php echo $forum_section_title; ?></em>&nbsp; Forum</h2>
          <form action="php_parsers/forumpost_system.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
            <input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="a" />
            Topic Author:<br /><input name="topic_author" type="text" disabled="disabled" maxlength="64" style="width:96%;" value="<?php echo $log_username; ?>" />
            <br /><br />
            Please type in a title for your topic here:<br /><input name="post_title" type="text" maxlength="64" style="width:96%;" /><br /><br />
            Please type in your topic body:<br />
            <textarea name="post_body" id="post_body" rows="15" style="width:96%;"></textarea>
            <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'post_body' );
            </script>
            <!--<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField" style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;"></iframe>-->
            <br /><br />
            <input name="" type="submit" value="Create my topic now!" onclick="validateMyForm();"/>
            <input name="fsid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $forum_section_id; ?>"/>
            <input name="fstitle" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $forum_section_title; ?>"/>
            <input name="uid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $log_id; ?>"/>
            <input name="uname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $log_username; ?>"/>
            <input name="upass" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $log_password; ?>"/>
          </form>
        </td>
        <td width="20%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <div id="rightPanel"></div>
</div>
<?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have your answer as I don't use nicEdit but is there a particular reason to use a non-active library (instead of something like CKEditor, Aloha Editor or tinyMCE) ?

Comment: @BabyAzerty What do u suggest me to do? This is really important for me. Please help

Comment: Well, I don't really recommend you to use something that was officially dropped 2 years ago. Beyond having no additional feature, you won't get much help (for example who can help you today with a Windows 95 issue ? who will even WANT to help you ?) and there might still be some rare bugs in the library. You can go for CKEditor if you want an easy full editor. If you use Twitter-Bootstrap, you can go for Summernote editor (very simple).

Comment: Is implementing CKEditor simple? I did not find any installation guide for CKEditor. Any idea where I can find it?

Comment: Here : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation

Comment: @BabyAzerty I'm having the same problem now also :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Put all your scripts at the end of the body (only put libraries in the head).
2. You may have updated your post with code, but what is the current question now ?
3. I believe your question has changed a lot, so people who know CKEditor won't help you on this question because it originally says NicEdit. Better create a new question if you wish for more help.